# In the past, how long have Up-to-date OS upgrades taken to arrive?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I've bought a Macbook Pro Retina display before Mountain Lion was released. I have signed up for a copy of Mountain Lion for free, as promised by Apple if you purchase an Apple computer after June 11, 2012. When I finished the application form, the page said to wait till I get an email from Apple.

The problem is I don't know how long to wait. If past is prologue, how long is it before I can expect to get Mountain Lion? It has been three hours, and I still have not received an email.

Comment: this is the first day of release - they are probably overloaded with traffic

Comment: Should I expect it to come within the next day or two? Week? or Hours?

Comment: I got my code in 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a real issue, per [this MacRumors article](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/07/25/apples-os-x-mountain-lion-up-to-date-program-experiencing-early-hiccups/) from earlier today:

> Apple support staff have acknowledged the difficulties and are advising customers that they may need to wait up to three days to receive replacement codes, although some replacement codes are reportedly already coming through without any action required by the users.

Hopefully your codes will arrive within that window - if not, I recommend you contact Apple support; given proof-of-purchase on your MacBook, they should get you sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a call to Apple tomorrow to ask if you should fill out the form again. There have been some credible reports that people have received redemption codes in the email from Apple, but that those codes did not work. I don't think you fall into that category since you would have at lease received one email from Apple.

Of course, check your spam mail folder and perhaps try to enter the web form again, and watch for errors. I don't think there's anything the retail stores could do if you went in - so calling might be good to know if it's OK to re-enter the web form or if someone needs to correct this by hand.

Sorry for the news, but I wouldn't count on it working out if you would rather not wait a week or more for the new bits.

Comment: I also echo the sentiment of the person saying that due to the huge rush - if you do get a long hold time or someone that can't assist or get you to someone who can, it might be shorter for you to wait until the rush dies down. :-(